# How to parse generic key with kotlin serialization from JSON

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I am struggling with come up with idea how to properly parse JSON like this:

```
{
  "generic_key": { "version":1, "ttl":42 }
}
```

where expected kotlin class should look like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Config(val version: Int, val ttl: Long) {
  @Transient
  var key: String? = null // <== here comes generic_key
}
```

**UPDATE**

What I want to achieve is to get a kotlin class from string JSON and I don't know what key will be used as "generic_key".

**UPDATE 2**

Even something like this is okey for me:

```
@Serializable
data class ConfigWrapper(val map: Map<String, Config>)
```

Where there would be map with single item with key from jsonObject (e.g. generic_key) and with rest parsed with standard/generated Config.serializer.

Comment: fyi, I would say that it's really bad practice to have an API with keys that can change like that. If it's not an external API I would suggest improving the API instead

Comment: @Ivo Beckers, unfortunately it is, it is downloaded from BE and cannot be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1.** Define a custom deserializer, which will use plugin-generated serializer for `Config` class:

```kotlin
object ConfigDeserializer : DeserializationStrategy<Config> {
    private val delegateSerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), Config.serializer())
    override val descriptor = delegateSerializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Config {
        val map = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegateSerializer)
        val (k, v) = map.entries.first()
        return v.apply { key = k }
    }
}
```

To use it, you'll need to manually pass it to the `decodeFromString` method:

```kotlin
val result: Config = Json.decodeFromString(ConfigDeserializer, jsonString)
```

**Option 2.** Define a surrogate for `Config` class and a custom serializer, which will use plugin-generated serializer for `ConfigSurrogate` class, so that you could reject plugin-generated serializer for `Config` class and wire this custom serializer to `Config` class:

```kotlin
@Serializable
@SerialName("Config")
data class ConfigSurrogate(val version: Int, val ttl: Long)

object ConfigSerializer : KSerializer<Config> {
    private val surrogateSerializer = ConfigSurrogate.serializer()
    private val delegateSerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), surrogateSerializer)
    override val descriptor = delegateSerializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Config {
        val map = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegateSerializer)
        val (k, v) = map.entries.first()
        return Config(v.version, v.ttl).apply { key = k }
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Config) {
        surrogateSerializer.serialize(encoder, ConfigSurrogate(value.version, value.ttl))
    }
}

@Serializable(with = ConfigSerializer::class)
data class Config(val version: Int, val ttl: Long) {
    // actually, now there is no need for @Transient annotation
    var key: String? = null // <== here comes generic_key
}
```

Now, custom serializer will be used by default:

```kotlin
val result: Config = Json.decodeFromString(jsonString)
```

Comment: Even though my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953795/1642090 works as well I will accept this as correct answer, because especially option 1 is what I have been looking for :) thx

Comment: After all I have to admit that option 2 is more robust and reusable since it can be used e.g. for Ktor while option 1 cannot (or I don't know how :D )

Answer (score 1):

At the end this works for me, but if there is more straight forward solution let me know.

```
private val jsonDecoder = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
private val jsonConfig = "...."

val result = jsonDecoder.parseToJsonElement(jsonConfig)
result.jsonObject.firstNonNullOf { (key, value) ->
 config = jsonDecoder.decodeFromJsonElement<Config>(value).also {
   it.key = key // this is generic_key (whatever string)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following data classes

```
   data class Config(
    
      @SerializedName("generic_key" ) var genericKey : GenericKey? = GenericKey()
    
    )
    
    data class GenericKey (
    
      @SerializedName("version" ) var version : Int? = null,
      @SerializedName("ttl"     ) var ttl     : Int? = null
    
    )
```

Comment: I don't know what is "generic_key" in ahead, that's why is it called generic :)
I update my question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If the key is dynamic and different, the map structure should be fine

```
@Serializable
data class Config(val version: Int, val ttl: Long)

val result = JsonObject(mapOf("generic_key" to Config(1, 42)))
```

Comment: Yep, this is clear how to serialize known kotlin class, but other way is my issue.
See updated question, if it is more clear.